# Including a hyphen in a regex character bracket?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, testing, validation

```
$.validator.addMethod('AZ09_', function (value) { 
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+$/.test(value); 
}, 'Only letters, numbers, and _-. are allowed');
```

When I use somehting like `test-123` it still triggers as if the hyphen is invalid. I tried `\-` and `--`

Comment: My issue was that I was actually using method AZ09 and not AZ09_..gr

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Escaping using `\-` should be fine, but you can also try putting it at the beginning or the end of the character class. This should work for you:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/
```

Comment: Putting the hyphen last does NOT work with some Microsoft tools, like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Escaping they hyphen does work.

Comment: @SabaAhang because if it's at the beginning or the end it can't be between two other characters to create a range of characters (e.g. `[0-9]`)

Comment: @SabaAhang the following documentation page mentions that hyphen can be unescaped in the beginning or end of character brackets: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Putting the hyphen (`-`) last worked for me with `.clang-format`.

Answer (score 41):

Escaping the hyphen using `\-` is the correct way.

I have verified that the expression `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+$/` does allow hyphens. You can also use the `\w` class to shorten it to `/^[\w.\-]+$/`.

(Putting the hyphen last in the expression actually causes it to not require escaping, as it then can't be part of a range, however you might still want to get into the habit of always escaping it.)

Comment: Very nice. :D I prefer the readability though ( I guess \w would be easy for some experts though)

Comment: Putting the hyphen last does NOT work with some Microsoft tools, like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Escaping they hyphen does work.

Answer (score 4):

The \- maybe wasn't working because you passed the whole stuff from the server with a string. If that's the case, you should at first escape the \ so the server side program can handle it too.

- In a server side string: \\-
- On the client side: \-
- In regex (covers): -

Or you can simply put at the and of the [] brackets.

Comment: I needed on the server side using C#. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Topman Better yet (for C#), use [verbatim string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) for server-side regex, filenames, etc. to avoid confusion (`@"\"` instead of `"\\"`).

Answer (score 4):

Generally with hyphen (`-`) character in regex, its important to note the difference between escaping (`\-`) and not escaping (`-`) the hyphen because hyphen apart from being a character themselves are parsed to specify range in regex.

`In the first case`, with escaped hyphen (`\-`), regex will only match the hyphen as in example `/^[+\-.]+$/`

`In the second case`, not escaping for example `/^[+-.]+$/` here since the hyphen is between plus and dot so it will match all characters with ASCII values between 43 (for plus) and 46 (for dot), so will include comma (ASCII value of 44) as a side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

`\-` should work to escape the `-` in the character range. Can you quote what you tested when it didn't seem to? Because it seems to work: http://jsbin.com/odita3

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way of matching hyphens is by using the character class for hyphens and dashes ("\p{Pd}" without quotes). If you are dealing with text from various cultures and sources, you might find that there are more types of hyphens out there, not just one character. You can add that inside the [] expression

Answer (score -1):

Desipite being the accepted answer fine in most of the cases, working with field HTML/CSS validation I've found some problems even escaping, not only the hyphen, but also other characters such as the space (\s) or the dot (.).
Normally a single scape `\-` would do the work, but in validation seems to require  **double escaping** them, i.e. escape the the escaping backslash: `\\-`

**12/07/2023 update**: Having to double escape REGEX reserved chars seems related to the fact of using a JS compiler (in my case Ember-cli). The single escape works fine in a codepen.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: See [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](/q/17863066/4642212). This doesn’t seem relevant.

Comment: @Sebastian Simon, maybe you should ask before shooting... Is true that I haven't clarifyed that the issue I described was with HTML patterns, but putting a negative and saying is not relevant I think is too much. Many user may get here through google search, looking for an answer although they are not validating via JS, but with HTML pattern REGEX, why you think my contribution wouldn't be useful to them?