# JavaScript Regular Expression to match some special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this regular expression to match any string contains only English letters `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/`

Now I need to edit this to make to match dashes '-' and dots '.' along with English letters.
the string may contains dash or dot or non(just letters).

Any Idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including a hyphen in a regex character bracket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697202/including-a-hyphen-in-a-regex-character-bracket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `-` and `.` in the character class like this :

```
/^[-.a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

Comment: +1 for not escaping the dot in the character class, like you see all too often...

Answer (score 1):

For `-` and `.` and *spaces*:

```
/^[-a-z\s.]+$/i
// "Foo-bar" OK
// "Foo.bar" OK
// "Foo bar" OK
// "Foo - bar" OK
// "Foo.bar-zaz" OK
// "Foo.bar-zaz TROZ" OK
```

For `-` or `.` or *spaces*:

```
/^[a-z\s]+$|^[-a-z]+$|^[a-z.]+$/i
// "Foo-bar" OK
// "Foo.bar" OK
// "Foo bar" OK
// "Foo - bar" FAIL
// "Foo.bar-zaz" FAIL
// "Foo.bar-zaz TROZ" FAIL
```

Let me explain:

`/i` ignore case, so you don't need `A-Z`

`|` (pipe) do the or for you.

`^` at begin of your string

`$` until the end

Now just about inside char restrictions `[...]`:

Put the `-` in the begin of the char restriction is good practice because it indicates a range in many ways, so put in the begin avoid mistakes.

`\s` blank space (can't range in JS)

`.` inside `[.]` is just a dot, but outside means any character (even invisible ones).

Comment: You need to put `-` at the end of the character class. Else you are creating a range from `\s` to `.`

Comment: @RohitJain No I'm not... I tested the code, be more expecific with what you means please

Comment: When you use `-` in the middle of a character class, it has a special meaning, and is used as range. To match `-` literally, you should place it at either ends of character class. So: - `[\s-.]` is not the same as: - `[-\s.]` or `[\s.-]`.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't think so dude, check here: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php if you are right the code must accept `¹²³` and NOT accept `-` and that isn't the case.

Comment: @RohitJain for javascript regexp it will not work as you said, because `\s` don't do range, but I have changed for good practices.

Comment: @Gabriel Gartz **the string may contains dash or dot or non(just letters)**
So at least one character is required.

Comment: @NaveedS thanks, I get your point, my understanding the English language fail lot of times... But he said **dash or dot or non(just letters)** so it means your code will work with dash AND dot AND non ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/^[a-zA-Z\s\-\.]+$/` will match what you need.

Comment: No need to escape `.` in character class and also `-` if placed following `[` or just before `]`

Comment: @NaveedS It may not be necessary, but it is clearer to me this way and you don't have to worry about where anything else is added to the class.

Comment: @G-Nugget.. Just a suggestion. If anyone gives you good advice, please take it. This is the way you learn. Else you will always do the same mistake for your lifetime.

Comment: @G-Nugget.. And also, it is clearer to you doesn't mean that it's a good idea, and also it will be clearer to the reader of your code. Remember - You don't write code for yourself, but for others. Cheers :)