# Rails Regex warning: character class has '-' without escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm doesn't know much about regex soo I just find some and try to use it.

Why I have this error for this regex:

```
warning: character class has '-' without escape: /[a-zA-Z0-9-._ ]/
```

What is wrong here?

validations shoud have only letters, numbers and "-" , "." , "_", " " (blank space)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

hyphen has **special meaning** in regex for *example* `[a-z]` means a to z character.

If you want to match `-` then it should either be **escaped** or be at the **end** (or **start**) of the class.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._ -]
```

OR

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]
```

OR

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-._ ]
```

**Read more** [Including a hyphen in a regex character bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697202/including-a-hyphen-in-a-regex-character-bracket)

Comment: Thanks i didn't know and find this example on net.

Answer (score 4):

If you put `-` inside a character class, you need to escape it because it has a special meaning(*range*) in character class. Or you could put the  `-` at the start or at the end of char class. If you do like this, it won't need escaping of `-` symbol inside character class.

Answer (score 4):

Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special** meaning. You can place a hyphen as the first or last character of the class. In some regular expression implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to add it to your class.

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]
```