# Valid regular expresssion doesn't compile in Python

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to filter some data using regular expressions, and came with one example that doesn't compile in python, even though it seems to be a valid expression.

I have reduced it to its minimal form :

```
test=re.compile(r'[e-+]')
```

Calling this in Python 3.6.1, I get an error. I don't get an error with `r'[e+-]'`, but I do get an error with `r'[e-+]'` ...

I don't understand why I get an error, because I know that '+' is a metacharacter, but in the manual : 'Metacharacters are not active inside classes'.

And I don't see why the order of the '-' and the '+' should matter ...

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697202/including-a-hyphen-in-a-regex-character-bracket   it's the hypen that is blowing you up.

Comment: `"Valid regular expresssion doesn't compile in Python"` It's not a valid regex:  https://regex101.com/r/FuVH24/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character '+' comes before the letter 'e', so the range '+-e' would make sense and matches any of the 59 characters from `'+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcde'`, but 'e-+' is not allowed because the start of the range comes after the end.

The character set `e+-` is completely different. That one just has the three characters mentioned as the `-` does not form a range when it is the first or last character.

Answer (score 2):

In a regular expression, the construct `[a-e]` matches 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', or 'e'. To explicitly match a '-', you must either escape it `\-` or put it right after the opening bracket or right before the closing bracket.