# Can LINQ be used to search for Regex expressions in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have the following code that works, but would like to edit it up using `LINQ` to find if any of the `Regex` search strings are in the target.

```
foreach (Paragraph comment in
            wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(comment => comment.InnerText.Contains("cmt")))
{
    //print values
}
```

More precisely I have to select through `LINQ` if the string start with letters or start with symbols `-` or `•`

This `Regex` is correct for my case ?

```
string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z-]+$";
Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
```

Any suggestion please?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: One thing is unclear: you have `comment => comment.InnerText.Contains("cmt")` which fetches items that contain `cmt` anywhere in the string, but in [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63976797/3832970) you say the string should start with `cmt`. Is it due to the fact these are for different scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex should be modified as

```
^[\p{L}•-]
```

To also allow whitespace at the start of the string add `\s` and use

```
^[\p{L}\s•-]
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[\p{L}•-]` - a letter, `•` or `-`
- `[\p{L}•-]` - a letter, whitespace, `•` or `-`

In C#, use

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^[\p{L}•-]");
foreach (Paragraph comment in
    wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>()
       .Where<Paragraph>(comment => reg.IsMatch(comment.InnerText)))
{
    //print values
}
```

If you want to match those items containing `cmt` and also matching this regex, you may adjust the pattern to

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^(?=.*cmt)[\p{L}\s•-]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

If you need to only allow `cmt` at the start of the string:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^(?:cmt|[\p{L}\s•-])");
```

Comment: Many thanks for reply. Your `regexp` working perfectly but I'm sorry but now I need check select through `LINQ` if the string start with letters or start with symbols `-` or `•` or `whitespace`, I have tried without success `^[\p{L}•- ]`

Comment: And your `regexp` not validate accented characters (Diacritics) as  `E’ `

Comment: @Kooper Diacritic is already the second char, so if the first one is a letter, it is already fine. To check if a string starts with whitespace, use `^[\p{L}\s•-]`. Always [put hyphen at the closing bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697202).

Answer (score 1):

You can. It would be better to use query syntax though, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-combine-linq-queries-with-regular-expressions

Example:

```
var queryMatchingFiles =  
            from file in fileList  
            where file.Extension == ".htm"  
            let fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.FullName)  
            let matches = searchTerm.Matches(fileText)  
            where matches.Count > 0  
            select new  
            {  
                name = file.FullName,  
                matchedValues = from System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches  
                                select match.Value  
            };
```

Your pattern is fine, just remove the `$` from the end and add any character

```
 @"^[a-zA-Z-]+. *"
```

Comment: Many thanks for help. I'm sorry but I don't understand: I need replace my `foreach` with your example or what? Please explain me...