# Why is .htaccess file not rewriting "-" in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

So, I have a site `http://example.com` and i have a db with articles and what not,
When the article id is `http://example.com/article` , everything is fine, the rewrite is done correctly, but when the ID is is `http://example.com/article-name` I get a 404.

This is the code:
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ID=$1
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)?$ index.php?CAT=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)?$ index.php?topic=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

article.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {
require_once 'con.php';
$ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['ID']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `blog_article` WHERE articleID = '$ID' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    header("Location: /");
}
else{
    include 'article.php';
}
} 
elseif (isset($_GET['CAT'])) {
      include 'c.php'; 
} 

elseif (isset($_GET['topic'])) { 
    include 't.php'; 
  } 
else {
include 'index_view.php';
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including a hyphen in a regex character bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697202/including-a-hyphen-in-a-regex-character-bracket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ID=$1
```

Means "if you see 1 or more letter or number in a sequence, rewrite it to index.php?ID=the_sequence_that_was_found"

The rule doesn't include any punctuation characters such as the `-`. If you'd like it to consider capturing letters, numbers and dashes, then the line should instead be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?ID=$1
```

Note that if you want to add more characters in here, you may need to escape them. This is because characters like the dash are a special character for these [regex patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so a backslash tells Apache that it should be a literal dash like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?ID=$1
```